# comparing active dates by user

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to compare lists of dates associated with users.

As an example:

```
user_id   |   visit_date
0000001   |   2018-03-12
0000001   |   2018-03-15
0000001   |   2018-03-27
0000002   |   2018-01-09
0000002   |   2018-02-01
0000002   |   2018-03-15
```

And I want to look, day by day, how many returning users we got where a returning user would be defined as someone who hadn't visited for four weeks but has now returned.

```
SELECT 
   a.user_id,
   a.active_date
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             visit_date as active_date,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by user_id ORDER BY visit_date DESC) as rank
      FROM table) a 
WHERE a.rank =1
```

Will give me a list, from today, of the player's most recent visit, what I want to do is to get this for any particular date so that, if we check on 2018-03-15 it will say user 2 was reactivated on that day but looking at 2018-02-01 will say they hadn't become inactive yet and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up sorting this out myself using the [lag window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) so thought I'd post my solution.

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.active_date,
    date_part('days',a.active_date - lag(a.active_date,1)OVER(partition by a.user_id ORDER BY a.active_date)) as days_since_last_visit
FROM (SELECT
        user_id,
        visit_date as active_date
      FROM table) a
```

This then gives me a table with dates and the time between that date and the most recent before that. Using the example above I get:

```
user_id   |   active_date    |    days_since_last_visit
0000001   |   2018-03-12     |       0
0000001   |   2018-03-15     |       3
0000001   |   2018-03-27     |       12
0000002   |   2018-01-09     |       0
0000002   |   2018-02-01     |       23
0000002   |   2018-03-15     |       42
```

And can then check whether the days since last visit is greater than 28.

(Still welcoming other solutions since I'm sure I've neither the neatest solution nor am I the only person who would be interested).